# How to send a string in route parameter? [Angular-Dart]

Tags: routes, url-routing, angular-dart

This is the route configuration:

```
const Route(path: '/kanji_list/:type/:value', name: 'List', component: KanjiList),
```

If I use only numbers in my route link, Angular will work:

```
[routerLink]="['List', {type: 5, value: 3}]
```

But I want to send a string as a parameter, like this:

```
[routerLink]="['List', {type: "jlpt", value: 5}]
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to send a string?

Comment: Is the error not at syntax level ?  Try this to see `[routerLink]="['List', {type:'jlpt', value: 5}]"`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was a syntax error as Christian Amani pointed out. I was using double quotes when Angular accepts single quotes syntax inside a map or list in the template. 
So changing this:

```
[routerLink]="['List', {type: "jlpt", value: 5}]"
```

To this:

```
[routerLink]="['List', {type:'jlpt', value: 5}]"
```

Fixed the problem.